# ajax request in drupal 7 not working

Tags: ajax, drupal, autocomplete, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have issue with auto complete in my drupal 7 site. Whenever an autocomplete request is sent then there is 9 appear at the end of each request.

Similar thing is happening on web page. 9 is appeared at the end of tag.

Please give me its solution.
here is the ajax result which comes along with 9

```
  An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
    HTTP Result Code: 200
    Debugging information follows.
    Path: node_reference/autocomplete/node/field_parent_textbook
StatusText: OK
ResponseText: {"Zondervan Atlas of the Bible [nid:4602]":"\u003cdiv class=\"reference-autocomplete\"\u003eZondervan Atlas of the Bible\u003c\/div\u003e"}9
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The most likely by far scenario is that you have some custom code that prints that by mistake. View your code, and make sure you do not `print` or `echo` anything.

Comment: I checked that but I did not find any thing that I echoed. Can you guide me from where ajax requests comes in drupal? how is the flow? why it is coming in each ajax request -response?

Comment: check any custom module you have built, as well as the template.php file in your theme. You normally shouldn't be worried about the exact internal structure (roughly: define `#autocomplete_path` in a form element and set to point to an existing path, which should return a JSON encoded array of results )

Comment: this 9 occur when I run cron.php also. There is not echo or print in cron.php still having this issue. Please suugest. As it is occuring in all system files I am confused where to debug

Comment: `cron.php` does bootstrap Drupal, so any .module file with `echo` or `print` will still create it. Try disabling custom modules until this is resolved, and enable one by one.